# Windows keeps switching to Ethernet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ethernet, connection-sharing

I have a wireless router whose WAN port is plugged into my laptop's Ethernet port, where WiFi sharing is used to provide an Internet connection. I notice though that many times, Windows will switch my active Internet connection to Ethernet, which prevents me from using the Internet on my laptop, and from any device connected to the router as well. With the Ethernet cable unplugged, the Wi-Fi signal doesn't drop out or anything, but sometimes fluctuates in signal strength. Is there any way to get Windows to not use the Ethernet port for Internet?

Comment: Two ways:  Unplug the Ethernet   Also (alternative) set the metric (network properties) so that Wireless ranks higher than Ethernet.

Comment: I assume you are using static IP for the Ethernet interface (because I don't see how otherwise could make sense). Have you set a default gateway for it? Because you shouldn't.

Comment: @John I don't want to disable my Ethernet interface since I am using that to communicate with the router, I just don't want to use it for an Internet connection on my laptop. I tried setting the metric of the WiFi interface to 5 and Ethernet to 1, which didn't seem to have any effect for me (please correct me if this isn't how that's supposed to be set up).